# onClick event not working upon clicking on a html button

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am working on a webpage which has about 8 html controls and a html button using which the data in the 8 html controls is submitted upon clicking on the button. 
I am trying to clear all the 8 fields once the button is clicked using JavaScript and I have the following script

HTML Page

```
<td>
     <select id="cbxProduct" data-bind="options: $root.productNames, optionsText: 'ProductName', optionsValue: 'ProductName', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Product'">
     </select>
</td>
<td>
     <select id="cbxTerm" data-bind="options: $root.termNames, optionsText: 'TermName', optionsValue: 'TermName', enable: selectedChoice, value: selectedTerm, optionsCaption: 'Term'">
     </select>
</td>
<td>
     <input type="text" id="txbBVolume" placeholder="Bid Volume"  data-bind="value:     bidVolume" />
</td>
<td>
     <select id="cbxBCP" data-bind="options: $root.counterpartyNames, optionsText: 'CounterPartyName', optionsValue: 'CounterPartyName', value: selectedBidCounterParty, optionsCaption: 'Bid CP'">
     </select>
</td>
<td>
     <input type="text" id="txbB" placeholder="Bid" data-bind="value: bid" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="txbO" placeholder="Offer" data-bind="value: offer" />
</td>
<td>
     <select id="cbxOCP" data-bind="options: $root.counterpartyNames, optionsText: 'CounterPartyName', optionsValue: 'CounterPartyName', value: selectedOfferCounterParty, optionsCaption: 'Offer CP'">
     </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="txbOVolume" placeholder="Offer Volume" data-  bind="value: offerVolume" />
</td>

<td >
     <input type="button"  class="btn btn-success" data-bind="      click: clear" value="Add New Entry" />
</td>
@section scripts {
 <script src="~/App/ClearAllFields.js"></script>
}
```

Knockout JS

```
self.add = function (cc) {
    var payload = {
        Term: this.selectedTerm(), Product: this.selectedChoice(), 
        BidCP: this.selectedBidCounterParty(), BidVolume: (this.bidVolume() == "") ? null : this.bidVolume(),  Bid: (this.bid() == "") ? null : this.bid(), Offer: (this.offer() == "") ? null : this.offer(),
        OfferVolume: (this.offerVolume() == "") ? null : this.offerVolume(), OfferCP: this.selectedOfferCounterParty(), Locked: false, Sequence: "", TermID: 0, ProductID: 0
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/odata/CC',
        type: 'POST',
        //  data: ko.toJSON(payload),
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    this.selectedChoice("Product");
    this.selectedTerm("Term");
    this.selectedBidCounterParty("Bid CP");
    this.bVolume("");
    this.bid("");
    this.offer("");
    this.oVolume("");
    this.selectedOfferCounterParty("Offer CP");
}
```

I thought everything is fine and it clears the TextBox fields but doesn't clear the dropdownboxes.

For Example, I have submitted `product=abc, term=fall, bVolume=5, BCP=X, Bid=10, Offer=12, OCP=C, OVolume=6` by clicking on `"Add new entry"` button and once I click the button, it submits the data and clears all the textbox fields bVolume,Bid,Offer,oVolume and leave the dropdown boxes as they are

Comment: Didn't find any reasons for down votes but never mind of them, would have been helpful if a comment is left with a down vote.

Comment: Could it be that `data-bind="      click: add"` overrides `onclick` attribute?

Comment: What is `data-bind`?  Is that part of a JavaScript framework?  I searched for it and it brings up [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) Are you using this?  If so, edit your question and add a tag for it because I don't think there is a convention for `data-bind` (other than the `data-` attribute on tags) in natural HTML/JS.

Comment: I tried calling both in a single click but it only one function worked in it

Comment: @zero298 Yes, it is KnockOut JavaScript and  I have necessary references to it in my code

Comment: If it's data bound, wouldn't you clear the model object that the fields are bound to?

Comment: The same reason it doesn't work [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/AJfjL/), you are circumventing knockout to make the data change, thus the model doesn't receive the changes.

Comment: @Origineil. Thanks and I edited the question as you suggested. I have added a knockout function but it doesn't clear the fields as it should. Please look at the edited question for knockout function

Comment: I presume  you are referring to the two properties (`selectedChoice`, `selectedTerm`) that you provided in the snippet, which would be the corresponding values to your `<select>` elements, but your elements do not have a `value` binding against those model properties.

Comment: Can you provide us with the full clear code? Can you make a complete JSFiddle for this please?

Comment: @Dev Can you please use jsfiddle and show us the code so we can debug it and help you out?

Comment: @WayneEllery . Some how I managed to clear the textbox fields but still could not do that with dropdowns. Please refer to the updated question

Comment: @DianaNassar Please refer to the updated question

Comment: @Dev You should be using the value binding for the dropdowns and have an observable that stores the selected option. You can then reset the option by changing the value of the observable.

Comment: You should read this which talks about options bindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `this.selectedChoice("Product");` to `this.selectedChoice("");`

By the way, remove all the id properties from the controls, because:

1. You don't need them.
2. It's against KnockoutJS principles.
3. You don't need them. :)

**EDIT:**

Change `this.selectedChoice("Product");` to `this.selectedChoice(null);`

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/e35aU/1/

Comment: I tried the way you said too but didnt work and about Id's, earlier I was working on JavaScript and used them

Comment: Is it declared as this.selectedChoice = ko.observable(); in the first place?

Comment: Yes it is without that I would not be able to submit anything, I mean without declaration

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value binding:

```
<select id="cbxProduct" data-bind="options: $root.productNames, value: selectedChoice">
</select>
```

Here is a quick demo of how to reset drop downs:

http://jsfiddle.net/4hVf4/

Comment: @Dev I've added a small demo of how to do it

Comment: Without seeing your full code it's very difficult to see why it's not working. Are you sure you need to use optionsValue and optionsText? Can you please provide your full viewmodel code?

Comment: the answer is almost similar to my question after updating my question, I still have the same issue but your JSFiddle is absolutely fine and same thing is not working on my page, strange

Comment: What is root.productNames? is it an array of objects or just an array of strings?

Comment: it is an array of string which has list of product Names pulled from a database table